# Store shapes in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I'm Trying to insert shapes into my mysql.

Is there any way to save shapes to my database.
 Which can then be restored at a later time.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
```

public class MyApp extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private List<Shape> shapes;
private Canvas canvas;
Shape shapeObject = null;
// private JButton btnClear;
private JColorChooser cc;
private JButton btnLoad;
private JButton btnSave;

Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;
```

public MyApp() {

```
    setResizable(false);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1348, 660);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JRadioButton[] shape = getShapesRadioButtons();
    for (int i = 0; i < shape.length; i++) {
        this.getContentPane().add(shape[i]);
    }
    JCheckBox[] color = getColor();
    for (int i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
        this.getContentPane().add(color[i]);
    }

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.setBounds(608, 56, 724, 565);
    contentPane.add(canvas);


    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mr) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            shapeObject.pos.x1 = mr.getX();
            shapeObject.pos.y1 = mr.getY();
            shapeObject.pos.calculate();

            if (shapeObject.pos.x > shapeObject.pos.x1) {
                shapeObject.pos.x2 = shapeObject.pos.x;
                shapeObject.pos.x = shapeObject.pos.x1;
                shapeObject.pos.x1 = shapeObject.pos.x2;
            }
            if (shapeObject.pos.y > shapeObject.pos.y1) {
                shapeObject.pos.y2 = shapeObject.pos.y;
                shapeObject.pos.y = shapeObject.pos.y1;
                shapeObject.pos.y1 = shapeObject.pos.y2;
            }

            shapes.add(shapeObject);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            shapeObject.pos.x = e.getX();
            shapeObject.pos.y = e.getY();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

        }

    });

    // Add Shapes jButtons

    shapes = new LinkedList<>();

    cc = new JColorChooser(canvas.getForeground());
    cc.setBounds(10, 267, 592, 354);
    cc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
    contentPane.add(cc);

    btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.setBounds(513, 243, 89, 23);
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnSave);

}

private ActionListener createActionListener(String shapeType) {
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")) {
                shapeObject = new Circle();
            } else if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Square")) {
                shapeObject = new Square();
            } else if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Rectangle")) {
                shapeObject = new Rectangle();
            } else if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Line")) {
                shapeObject = new Line();
            }
        }
    };
    return al;
}

private ActionListener getColor(String color) {
    ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("White")) {
                canvas.setBackground(Color.white);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("Black")) {
                canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("Red")) {
                canvas.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("Blue")) {
                canvas.setBackground(Color.blue);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("Green")) {
                canvas.setBackground(Color.green);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("Yellow")) {
                canvas.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    };
    return a;
}
```

private JCheckBox[] getColor() {

```
    JCheckBox[] color = new JCheckBox[6];
    color[0] = new JCheckBox("White");
    color[0].setBounds(500, 200, 20, 20);
    color[0].addActionListener(getColor("White"));
    color[0].setBackground(Color.white);

    color[1] = new JCheckBox("Black");
    color[1].setBounds(520, 200, 20, 20);
    color[1].addActionListener(getColor("Black"));
    color[1].setBackground(Color.black);

    color[2] = new JCheckBox("Red");
    color[2].setBounds(540, 200, 20, 20);
    color[2].addActionListener(getColor("Red"));
    color[2].setBackground(Color.red);

    color[3] = new JCheckBox("Blue");
    color[3].setBounds(500, 220, 20, 20);
    color[3].addActionListener(getColor("Blue"));
    color[3].setBackground(Color.blue);

    color[4] = new JCheckBox("Green");
    color[4].setBounds(520, 220, 20, 20);
    color[4].addActionListener(getColor("Green"));
    color[4].setBackground(Color.green);

    color[5] = new JCheckBox("Yellow");
    color[5].setBounds(540, 220, 20, 20);
    color[5].addActionListener(getColor("Yellow"));
    color[5].setBackground(Color.yellow);

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(color[0]);
    bg.add(color[1]);
    bg.add(color[2]);
    bg.add(color[3]);
    bg.add(color[4]);
    bg.add(color[5]);

    return color;

}
```

private JRadioButton[] getShapesRadioButtons() {
        JRadioButton[] shape = new JRadioButton[4];

```
    shape[0] = new JRadioButton("Circle");
    shape[0].addActionListener(createActionListener("Circle"));
    shape[0].getColorModel();
    shape[0].setBounds(10, 200, 60, 60);

    shape[1] = new JRadioButton("Square");
    shape[1].addActionListener(createActionListener("Square"));
    shape[1].setBounds(70, 200, 80, 60);

    shape[2] = new JRadioButton("Rectangle");
    shape[2].addActionListener(createActionListener("Rectangle"));
    shape[2].setBounds(150, 200, 100, 60);

    shape[3] = new JRadioButton("Line");
    shape[3].addActionListener(createActionListener("Line"));
    shape[3].setBounds(250, 200, 80, 60);

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(shape[0]);
    bg.add(shape[1]);
    bg.add(shape[2]);
    bg.add(shape[3]);

    return shape;
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Color newColor = cc.getColor();
    canvas.setForeground(newColor);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        shape.paintComponent((Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics());

    }

    /*
     * for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) { Shape shape =
     * shapes.get(i);
     * shape.paintComponent((Graphics2D)canvas.getGraphics()); }
     */}}
```

Also there is some classes for calculation & drawing shapes

Comment: Consider reading about serialization in Java: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm.

Answer (score 1):

I would say one option is to make the objects you want to persist in the Database serializable and then store them in BLOB columns.

You'll find lots of tutorials on serialization online, this is just one of them: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm